# How do I print a field from the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

How do I print any field from a .bib file?

For example how do I print the title from the following entry?

```
@article{Gerace2019,
Author = {Gerace, Dario and Laussy, Fabrice and Sanvitto, Daniele},
Journal = {Nature Materials},
Number = {3},
Pages = {200--201},
Title = {Quantum nonlinearities at the single-particle level},
Volume = {18},
Year = {2019}
}
```

I want to do something like:

```
The title of the paper \cite{Gerace2019} is \printtitle{Gerace2019}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using `biblatex` the command you are looking for is called `\citetitle`.

For the most common fields `biblatex` has dedicated `\cite...` commands (`\citeauthor`, `\citetitle`, `\citedate`, `\cityear`, `\citeurl`) if the field you want to print is not amongst those, then you can use the generic `\citefield{<key>}{<field>}`. Since `biblatex` differentiates between fields, lists and name lists, there are `\citefield`, `\citelist` and `\citename`, see also [How to extract BibTeX entries (as DOI, abstract, etc.)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207591/35864). It is possible to create your own `\cite...` command for fields that don't have one yet (see also the previous link).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Gerace2019,
  author  = {Gerace, Dario and Laussy, Fabrice and Sanvitto, Daniele},
  journal = {Nature Materials},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {200--201},
  title   = {Quantum nonlinearities at the single-particle level},
  volume  = {18},
  year    = {2019},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
The title of the paper \cite{Gerace2019} is \citetitle{Gerace2019}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The title of the paper [1] is ‘Quantum nonlinearities at the single-particle level’]

---

If you are using a BibTeX-based solution, you can load the [`usebib` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/usebib) and use its `\usebibentry` command.

Note that `usebib` does not parse the field contents like BibTeX or Biber. In particular, name lists and other lists are not split up as usual. That means that while it is possible to display name fields like `author` with `usebib`, the output will look exactly as the input in the `.bib` file.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{usebib}


%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Gerace2019,
  author  = {Gerace, Dario and Laussy, Fabrice and Sanvitto, Daniele},
  journal = {Nature Materials},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {200--201},
  title   = {Quantum nonlinearities at the single-particle level},
  volume  = {18},
  year    = {2019},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibinput{\jobname} % give the file name of your .bib file here (without extension)
                    % just as in \bibliography

\begin{document}
The title of the paper \cite{Gerace2019} is \usebibentry{Gerace2019}{title}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: The title of the paper [1] is Quantum nonlinearities at the single-particle level]

Comment: Wow that was quick. Thanks!

Comment: Is there also a way to check if a filed is defined, e.g. if `\citefield{key}{note}` would return an actual note or a placeholder?

Comment: @white_gecko I don't think there is a user-level command like `\citefield` (and I couldn't find one in the documentation just now, but there is lots in there, so I might just have forgotten it and not searched for the right keywords). There is `\iffieldundef`, but that can only be used inside a `\DeclareCiteCommand`. What exactly do you have in mind (use case)? I guess this would be a good topic for a new question.

Comment: Your comment and this helped me already: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73801/11820 Don't know if a new question would just be duplicate to this one.

Comment: @white_gecko If you found a solution that works for you (especially if you found it on this site), a new question might not be necessary.