# Is it possible to cite title with apacite?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

How can one, if possible, cite the title of a bibtex item on Latex using the package apacite?

Comment: You can't (easily) do that with `apacite` alone, but you can use [`usebib`](https://ctan.org/pkg/usebib). See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/478749/35864

Comment: @Raaja The question is a bit vague on the details, but if I understand correctly this is not about citations not working at all, it is specifically about producing the title in the citation where normally author and year are shown. In any case asking the OP if running BibTeX helps before casting the close vote might make for a more pleasant experience.

Comment: Thanks moewe - that solved my problem

Comment: Very well. Thanks for the confirmation. I voted to close the question as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/478749/35864 as linked in my first comment.

Comment: @moewe it was unclear for me as well, that's why -- from ky understanding -- I marked it as duplicate based on your link. Nevertheless, from next time, I will wait a bit more time for the OP's reply.

Comment: @Mico thanks for the clarification, but I do not exactly understand what you mean by the question mark.