# Reading information from .bib file with lua?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, luatex, lua

I'm wondering if it's possible to access the information in a .bib file using Lua code in LuaTeX. Basically, I have a function where I'd like to be able to add idiosyncratic custom citation styles for certain works that rely on information other than the standard author/title/year available in most citation packages.

I'm also open to a non-Lua way of doing this, but I haven't found any clear answers yet. The goal is to be as parsimonious as possible in terms of not having to duplicate information in multiple .lua/.bib/.tex files.

Edit: Upon request, a MWE:

We have a .bib that contains the following two entries:

```
@book{yassawi1904,
  author={Yassawī, Xoca Aḥmad bin Ibrāḥīm bin Muḥammad bin Iftiḥār},
  title={Dīwān-i Ḥikmat},
  publisher={Imperatorskaja Universitet},
  editor={(anon.)},
  address={Kazan},
  year={1904}
}

@book{yassawi2013,
  author={Yassawī, Xoca Aḥmad bin Ibrāḥīm bin Muḥammad bin Iftiḥār},
  title={Diwani Hikmet},
  publisher={Living Zen Books},
  editor={Johnathan Trapman},
  address={Glastonbury},
  year={2013}
}
```

We want to be able to produce a citation that looks something like this:

> This word appears as *blah* in ed. Kazan (1904), but this seems to be an error for *bleh*, as reflected in ed. Trapman (2013).

where the first would be based on a function that uses the address, and the latter the name of the editor.

Edit: To be clear, I'm not having trouble writing the Lua; just asking if its possible in any way (Lua or not) to write a function that access bib information like this.

Comment: ConTeXt, based on Lua, handles bibliography that way, so it's possible with LuaLaTeX too. A MWE (minimal working example) would be helpful

Comment: Pretty sure what you want can be done with `biblatex` but more detail is needed.

Comment: Thanks to both! MWE now added.

Comment: Forgot to @JairoADelRio re: edit.

Comment: Forgot to @HenriMenke re: edit.

Comment: `biblatex` has `\citefield` and friends, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207591/35864. If you don't want to use `biblatex`, you can take `usebib`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/478749/35864 (which out of the box will only work well for literal fields, if you have a name field, additional work would be needed).

Comment: @moewe That's a good fix for this one. Sorry, not sure why I couldn't find that on my own. Thanks!