# how to create a command to know if the fields exist in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, macros

I need to know if a .bib file has fields such as PUBLISHER, DOI, URL, JOURNAL or are empty, this in order to create another new command where I can put conditionals and be able to automatically generate image citations according to APA. So far I have been able to know if the DOI, Journal and URL fields exist or are empty, but I HAVE NOT BEEN ABLE TO DETERMINE IF THE PUBLISHER FIELD EXISTS WITHOUT THE UNDEFINED ERROR APPEARING (if it is empty ) AT the time of running it in OVERLEAF.

NOTE, I have tried the same thing to do with the create command to know if it is a file using the \ifentrytype conditional to know if it is an article or book, but without any result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % para \ifstrequal
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,
maxbibnames=3,minbibnames=1]{biblatex}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

% MI JOURNAL
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citejournal}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{journal}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

% MI URL 
\DeclareCiteCommand{\miurl}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{url}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

    
%PUBLISHER
\newcommand{\mipublisher}[1]{%
  \entrydata{#1}{%
    \iffieldundef{publisher}{%
      % Si el campo 'publisher' no está definido
      No hay publisher
    }{%
      % Si el campo 'publisher' está definido
      Hay publisher: \citelist{#1}{publisher} % Imprime el valor de publisher
    }%
  }%
}
  % DOI 
  \DeclareCiteCommand{\midoi}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex {\indexfield{indexdoi}}{}
  \iffieldundef{doi}{nd}{\printfield{doi}}}{\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
  
%DETERMINE IF IT IS AN ARTICLE OR A BOOK 
% Comando para verificar si una entrada es un artículo
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetypetest}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{entrytype}} % Modifica aquí para usar 'entrytype'
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
  
%
\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
  andmore = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}

\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}
%
\begin{document}


1) Doi-\midoi{Gonzales2010} \par 
2) Publisher- \mipublisher{Gonzales2010} \par  %
3) URL-\miurl{Gonzales2010} \par 
4) Journal-\citejournal{Gonzales2010} \par  %
5) mira esto: my \citelist{Garcia2022}{publisher} \par
6) \ifentrytype{article}{Es un artículo}{No es un artículo}
7) \mipublisher{Gonzales2010} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: publisher is a list, so you must test with `\iflistundef`.

Answer (score 2):

As [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) [points out in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/711945/how-to-create-a-command-to-know-if-the-fields-exist-in-biblatex#comment1769285_711945), `publisher` is a list, that's why you need to check if it is present with `\iflistundef{publisher}` and print it with `\printlist{publisher}`.

It is not entirely clear to me what exactly you are doing, but if you need a command that prints a special citation format for you, you should absolutely not have to use `\entrydata`. You should also not have to combine several `\cite...` commands into one.

Instead define one single command that produces the complete output you want with `\DeclareCiteCommand`.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/501331/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73799/35864.